# How to Save values into an existing table from UI-Component Form

Tags: magento2, model, uicomponent

My module contains a form which itself contains **Store Information** that is also in **Stores > Configuration > General > Store Information** 
[image: Store Information Form]
I have just followed this tutorial to create [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sampleform_form.xml) form but it did not mention how to store the values of it. BTW I want to save values in the `core_config_data` table. I have already read [this](https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-module-part-2-models/) tutorial too but it did not explain the `DataProvider` which is necessary in `ui-component`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below file in [vendorname]\[modulename]\Model\DataProvider.php

Thankyou.

### DataProvider.php

```
namespace [vendorname]\[modulename]\Model;

use [vendorname]\[modulename]\Model\ResourceModel\[resourcemodelname]\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $postCollectionFactory(CollectionFactory Variable)
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $postCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $postCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
      }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```